# SonarLint 3.2 with SonarQube 6.2

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea, sonarqube, sonarlint

Ha anyone else run into an issue when connecting the SonarLint plugin, version 3.2.0, to a SonarQube 6.2 server where the following error is thrown:

**java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/villagechief/sonar/salesforce/core/ApexCodeColorizer**

I connected the plugin to the SonarQube server in order to bind the project. It looks like the rules where pulled properly, but when I click on 'Analyze' or 'Analyze changed files', the error above is thrown.

These are my properties being passed:

extraProperties: {**sonar.java.source=1.8, sonar.java.target=1.8, sonar.libraries=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home**}